# in-class initialization of atomic

Tags: c++, atomic, in-class-initialization

Why in this example

```
struct Foo {
    atomic<int> x = 1;
};
```

the compiler (gcc 4.8) is trying to use the `atomic& operator=(const atomic&)` which is deleted, (hence the example wont compile), while here

```
struct Bar {
    Bar() { x = 1; }
    atomic<int> x;
};
```

it is calling the `int operator=(int)` as expected?

PS: I already know that

```
struct Xoo {
    atomic<int> x{1};
};
```

is fine (anyhow the better way to init `x`), but I am still curious about why `Foo` is broken.

PS: I misread the compiler error (and forgot to include it in the quesiton). It actually says:

```
 error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
   std::atomic<int> x = 1;
                        ^
 [...] error: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
       ^
```

so my above statement "...is trying to use the `atomic& operator=(const atomic&)` was just plain wrong.

Comment: Use `atomic<int> x{1};`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I already realized that this works, but still curious as to why `Foo` is broken

Comment: It has nothing to do with member initialization BTW, in normal scope, you will have the same issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 aaah, I guess it boils down to `T t = something;` beeing different from `T t; t = something;`. In that case it is a rather stupid question ;)

Comment: `T t = something` and `T t; t = something` are extremely different

Comment: The premise of the question is broken, because _"the compiler (gcc 4.8) is trying to use the `atomic& operator=(const atomic&)`"_ is not true.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition thats what the error message suggests (which I will add to the question in a second)

Comment: That's a very serious compiler bug if so. [Mine says: `error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad9988f833d9d015)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition maybe I should have read the error more carefully. Shame on me....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::atomic<int> x = 1;` is *copy-initialisation*, and basically does this:

```
std::atomic<int> x{std::atomic<int>{1}};
```

Your compiler actually doesn't complain about `operator=`, but instead about the copy constructor.

(As you've pointed out, a later `operator=` call works just fine.)

Do a normal initialisation:

```
std::atomic<int> x{1};
```

Comment: I would actually vote to close the quesiton as "misread the compiler error message", but as there are already answers I guess I can just accept one and take it as a lesson to pay more attention next time ;)

Comment: @tobi303: fbm :P

Answer (score 5):

```
atomic<int> x = 1; // not an assignment.
```

is

```
atomic<int> x{atomic<int>{1}};
```

whereas

```
atomic<int> x;
x = 1; // assignment
```